# Select information from mysql

Tags: mysql, search

My need is to select the destination from mysql

The database contains the following information

```
 IBIS, COUNTRY, REGION
 "AFG", "93";
 "AFG Mobile AWCC", "93", "70"
 "AFG Mobile ETSLAT", "93", "78"
 "AFG Mobile AREEBA", "93", "77"
 "AFG Mobile", "93", "75"
```

I am looking for information ZONE COUNTRY + the result should be IBIS

```
Search 1 :9378555555 => Mobile AFG ETSLAT
Search 2 :9377755555 => Mobile AFG AREEBA
Search 3 :9399999999 => AFG
```

Thank you for reading and response :)

+++++ UPDATE

```
"ALB Fixed ALBTEL";"355";"4249"
"ALB Tirana";"355";"422, 423, 4240, 4241, 4242, 4243, 4244, 4245, 4246, 4247, 4248"
```

Country var(3) and Region is concat ...

```
Search 1 :355424955555 => ALB Fixed ALBTEL
Search 2 :35542405555  => ALB Tirana
```

Comment: $x LIKE CONCAT(country,'%')?

Comment: Have you tried writing the query yourself?  If so, what have you tried?

Comment: @Strawberry yep but please read up date for question, sorry not to have been accurate early

Comment: Great. Now it's just nonsense. Start again. Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an SQLFIDDLE.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  COUNTRY = LEFT('9399999999', 2)
  AND (REGION = SUBSTRING('9399999999', 3, 2) OR REGION IS NULL)
ORDER BY
  REGION IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b68f/1).

**Edit**

Not the cleanest solution ever, but it looks okay to me:

```
SET @num = '35542405555';

SELECT *
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  @num LIKE CONCAT(COUNTRY, '%')
  AND (REGION IS NULL
       OR FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING(@num, LENGTH(COUNTRY)+1, 2), REPLACE(REGION, ' ', ''))
       OR FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING(@num, LENGTH(COUNTRY)+1, 3), REPLACE(REGION, ' ', ''))
       OR FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING(@num, LENGTH(COUNTRY)+1, 4), REPLACE(REGION, ' ', '')))
ORDER BY
  REGION IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29cb3/35). This is limited to REGIONs of 2, 3 or 4 characters.

Comment: Humm, good idea, but ...

"ALB Fixed ALBTEL";"355";"4249"
"ALB Tirana";"355";"422, 423, 4240, 4241, 4242, 4243, 4244, 4245, 4246, 4247, 4248"

Country var(3) and Region is concat ...